# How do you iterate through cells without using for each?

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to just be able to set the index of the Cells function with a loop so I can compare cells using control functions as such:

```
Sub cellsTest()
Dim i As Long
Dim price As Long

   For i = 1 To 100
   price = Cells(i, 6).Value
   MsgBox (price)
   Next i

End Sub
```

Yet this does not work.  This seems like being able to set a long type variable equal to a numerical cell value would be a fundamental operation of VBA.  I don't want to force this into a for-each format.  Is there someway to make this work?

Comment: works for me, what does not work for you?

Comment: It does not work on my installation for some reason.  I will have to further investigate this.  I get error 13 Type mis-match.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I get error 13 Type mis-match triggered at the "price = Cells(i, 6).Value" line.

Comment: what is the value of I at that point, and what is in that cell? sounds like you're trying to convert text to long

Comment: If the value is text or an error then it cannot be converted to a long and you will get that error.

Comment: Have you tried `Dim price As variant` ? Are there worksheet errors (e.g #N/A) in column F.

Comment: I just confirmed that the code works on a similar computer but not mine.  I am going to take a look at the references.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `price As Long` that means while assigning a value to the price variable, if the value being assigned is not numeric, the code will throw an error 13 Type Mismatch. i.e. if the column F contains a text string or error value, it will throw the error 13.

In that case, you should check if the value being assigned is numeric like below...

```
Sub cellsTest()
Dim i As Long
Dim price As Long

For i = 1 To 100
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 6)) Then
        price = Cells(i, 6).Value
        MsgBox (price)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is for numerical values only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Sub cellsTest()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim price As Variant

   For i = 1 To 3
      If Not IsError(Cells(i, 6).value) Then
         price = Cells(i, 6).value
         MsgBox price
      End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

If there is a reference to a cell that doesn't exist (Ie. cell contains `#REF!`) or some other error being detected, this will skip that cell and go onto the next.

Also, I change the type `Long` to type `Variant` as this will take any kind of input, rather than just an number.

Comment: This will fail given a non-numeric, non-error value (e.g. any non-numeric string)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Tested it just now, and it works fine for me. Can you give me an example value that this wouldn't work on?

Comment: Ah, that's because `price` is a `Variant`. If it's declared `As Long`, the implicit conversion fails. Might as well assign it before the `IsNumeric` check, and only read the cell value once then. Note the parens are superfluous in the `MsgBox` call.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Good catch on the `MsgBox` I missed that one. However, I think you might be confusing my answer with the above, I am using `IsError()` not `IsNumeric()`.